# How can I determine the transfer function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this inhomogeneous differential equation:

$$2*y'(t)+a*y(t)=\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\frac{1}{3+n^2}*e^{int}$$

I have to find the stationary solution. I know that you are supposed to determine the transfer function, but I don't know how to do that when there is a series in the differential equation.

I think you can set n = 1 and determine then you can determine the transfer function. And then you can generalize the transfer function and determine the sum of solutions. But my problem is that I just get stuck with the series.

Can someone help me with solving this problem?

Comment: Stationary means that the solution no longer changes with respect to time, i.e. $y'=0$. Does this help?

Comment: No not really. Can you elaborate?